# How can I securely store SQL information in a Windows Form project?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, security, sqlconnection

I couldn't find how to securely store SQL information in a C# windows forms application.

With tools like .NET Reflector, the code can appear somehow.

What is the most accurate and reliable method?

They suggest keeping it encrypted in app.config. However, decryption codes must be in the project.

Thus, it is easy to see how it is encrypted and how it can be decrypted.

Comment: If it is that critical, it should not connect the database directly. You may need to have a server application.

Comment: That depends on how you plan to distribute your app and where the DB is hosted. Is it downloadable from the internet and the whole world can use it? Then it's not possible AFAIK. But it might be if you use an external identity provider (e.g. Azure Active Directory). Is it a company app deployed internally? Then you can use the users identity and allow a specific user group access to the DB. You need to provide more details about your use case, because storing the credentials inside the app will always mean leaking them in some way.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride Thank you for the answer. This will be a SaaS application, so anyone who is a member will be able to download and use it.

Hundreds of thousands of people from any country and any IP address should be able to connect.

I can't put restrictions on IP addresses or anything. I have to hide SQL connection information well or I can connect via API but I still have to hide something.

As long as the exe's codes are visible, I have to encrypt some important information and not show how I encrypt it.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride I had looked into encrypting all the intermediate codes, but it was quite costly. I found a free tool and it had different problems. Even encrypting the codes may not be the definitive solution :(

Comment: @Eldar This application has to be a client running on the client.

Comment: Ok, I am not saying it otherwise. You should have a client application but not talking directly to the SQL server. Instead it should talk to a server application which talks to SQL

Comment: If it's SaaS then your users probably authenticate with a login in that app. Use their credentials to talk to a web API (created by you) which then executes the SQL and sends back the result data to your app.

Comment: It's not possible to completely hide information on a machine you do not control. You are wasting your time.

Comment: @GoodNightNerdPride, I agree with you. Do you recommend I use the Web API (RESTful API)?

Comment: @Charlieface There are thousands of apps running on similar model, there must be a way.

Comment: @Eldar I don't know Server Application, I will research it, thank you.

Comment: No there aren't. Most apps are running SaaS over a webserver now, the ones that are not have strict legal contracts to prevent copy theft

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to create a server application and route DB access through the server application.

There are ways to hide and encrypt sensitive data in an application e.g. by using `SecureString`. However there will always be point where the sensitive data exists in plaintext and this point will be the moment of weakness. All means of encryption will only reduce the amount of time sensitive data is present in a readable format for.

Thus using a server applications to act as an intermediary between your application and the client app is the best solution. As mentioned by @Good Night Nerd Pride, your server application will also need to implement authentication to ensure only authorised user's have access to the databse.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

I'll look into SecureString. I also think I should use API but I will still need to keep some variables in code for API connection. I'll have to hide them somehow again, won't I?

Do you recommend I use the Web API (RESTful API)?

Comment: To clarify, my mention of `SecureString` was more to discourage you from going down that route. It will just make it more difficult for an attacker to get the sensitive date not prevent it. If you really must go down that route, make sure to use some kind of a crendentials store to retrieve the credentials from and not a hard coded config file.

Comment: When assigning and reading the SecureString variable, I will need to add my connection information to the code again. So it can be seen how I created and used the SecureString variable. By doing the same, they can reach the same value.

I have to read the value I have defined from somewhere and no one should be able to see the value I read.

Comment: Hence why I said that you should create a server application and not use `SecureString`